# Undefined behaviour mixing static and dynamic variables within the same expression

Tags: c, gcc

The same expression evaluates differently when declaring a char array as static vs dynamic.

Can anyone explain why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINESIZE 12

#define SKIP        !strchr(       skip_line_char ,line[0])
#define SKIP_STATIC !strchr(static_skip_line_char ,line[0])
#define TAB         !strchr(line ,'\t')

int main() {

//static char line[LINESIZE]={'a','\n','\r'};
char line[LINESIZE]={'a','\n','\r'};

static char static_skip_line_char[]={'#','\n','\r'};
char skip_line_char[]={'#','\n','\r'};

    if (SKIP_STATIC && TAB)
        printf("\nstatic");

    if (SKIP && TAB) 
        printf("\ndynamic");

    return 0;
}
```

For line declared static the code returns "static"

For line declared dynamic the code returns

"static"
"dynamic"

The later being the correct answer as line[0] =='a'

Comment: Tell us exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: @OneArb Could you say what is the difference and what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get unpredictable results for this and possibly even a crash on some platforms.

strchr operates on null terminated arrays of characters (C strings) - because you haven't put a null terminator character in static_skip_line_char or skip_line_char they are unterminated and will possibly contain junk on the end as far as strchr is concerned.

For statics it is likely that the next memory element is zero which would happen to terminate it (because the static area is zero'ed by default).

To fix it you would need the following:

```
static char static_skip_line_char[]={'#','\n','\r','\0'};
char skip_line_char[]={'#','\n','\r','\0'};
```

Or more simply:

```
static char *static_skip_line_char="#\n\r";
char *skip_line_char="#\n\r";
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `strchr` expects null-terminated strings, but you are passing it a character array that does not have null termination.

Adding `'\0'` at the end will make both arrays behave the same way:

```
static char static_skip_line_char[]={'#','\n','\r','\0'};
char skip_line_char[]={'#','\n','\r','\0'};
```

or use string literal initialization, which adds null termination automatically:

```
static char static_skip_line_char[]="#\n\r";
char skip_line_char[]="#\n\r";
```

Comment: works as expected, I got fooled as it worked fine till I made skip_line_char static

Comment: @OneArb `'\0'` is a null character, not a zero character (i.e.`'0'`). C strings cannot contain null characters. This is the character that gets added automatically to the end of your string when you use string literals.

Comment: Detail: "C strings cannot contain null characters."  Maybe better said as "C strings always contain just one null character - the last one."